# Intel i386 82865G onboard graphics

Tags: intel-graphics

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 on a Gateway system. It has Intel i386 82865G onboard graphics. I've downloaded these drivers from the Intel page, they have "Linux" label, no specific version, the filename is "20030425-i386.tar.gz".

Being new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, I need help with how to install these drivers... thanks!

Comment: Are any drivers suggested when you open **Dash** (the "search" button) > **Software Sources** (type it to the search) > **Additional Drivers**? If it suggests something, install them. Compiling drivers from a source (the file you have downloaded) is often tough even for non-newbies.

Answer (score 1):

First install Ubuntu **12.04 LTS** (eg. 12.04.2), and see what drivers it already has. Then for any other device (or feature), ask on this forum.

---

Just downloading 'generic Linux' drivers may not help very much. These at least need to be for **Debian** (Ubuntu is based on this) or **RedHat/Fedora** (the other main variant). Then you are going to have to modify and configure them to suit the environment (OS) ..

What is going to work is a driver for the specific device and the specific variant of Linux (and 32/64bit, etc.). Anything else may not help you very much.